# How can I take pictures at preset times throughout a day?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, intervalometer, automation

I need to take a close up picture of an object at up to 8 different, pre-programmed times a day (i.e. 6:00am, 7:00am, 7:30am, 12:00pm, 2:30pm, 6:00pm, 7:00pm, 8:00pm).

I have looked at trail cameras but they seem to be mostly motion triggered.
Intervalometers seem to be only programmable at time intervals like every so many hours.

I will have Wifi access at the camera location and would like to minimize costs.

Comment: Hi Terri and welcome to photo.SE! I've edited to be more about solving the photographic program than about equipment recommendation as the answers for those questions become outdated very soon. You can rollback the edit if you don't like it.
Out of curiousity: *why* do you need to photograph an object up close at these times?

Comment: The object has a screen that changes and I need to record the changes of the screen at those times.

Comment: Ah right. The object doesn't have another way of accessing what's displayed on the screen? Maybe it has an USB or serial port or something?

Comment: Why do not use intervalometer every half hour and remove the unnecessary images?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to set an intervalometer to take a picture every 30 minutes (or whichever period matches all your needed times) and discard the images you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inexpensive Arduino to trigger a Canon camera. There is no additional hardware needed. A clock board is not needed. It can be calibrated with a few lines of code to keep accurate time. You could reset the clock every month.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Could you perhaps [edit] your answer to include how one would link an Arduino to a Canon camera? A link to some tutorial would already be helpful.

Comment: It depends on the Canon model. For most popular large DSLRs no tutorial is needed. Simply connect the shutter cable wire to a digital pin on Arduino. A 100 ohm resistor is optional to prevent damage to an unknown or untested model. Usually the shutter wire is one of the wires from the 3.5mm plug. Google for your particular model number.